# Copying a region of Calc cells into a Writer document as a table

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc, openoffice-writer, cut-and-paste

I need to take a region of spreadsheet cells and paste them into a Writer document as a table.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select and copy the cells from Calc.

In Writer:

> Edit > Paste Special

The *Paste Special* dialog will appear.

Select **HTML (HyperText Markup Language)** and click **OK**.

Your copied cells will now be pasted into the document as an HTML table.

For all intents and purposes this is now a table in Writer and not the embedded object you would have seen from a simple copy-paste.

Comment: This has been tested of a slight elaboration of the asker's own comment.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search brings up this thread: http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=44629

You can already paste as a new table, apparently. But to paste into an existing table, you need to first paste into a new document, then copy that and then paste it into the original table using the "Paste Special > HTML" command.

Comment: No. I appreciate the search help + the links to forums, that's helpful. But if you state something as fact please try it yourself first. When you paste a Calc cell region directly into a Writer document, you get this weird embedded object that looks awful + is different from a Writer table.

Comment: OK, here's what seems to work. You "Paste Special" as HTML directly as a new table in an empty Writer document. That yields a table. Then you can cut+paste cells normally in Writer.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @8Days' answer:

You must *Paste Special* into the top-level of the document. It does *not* work properly if you are creating a table inside a table cell (Writer gets confused), and you have to first paste special into the top-level of the document, then you can cut+paste into a table inside a table cell.